# InAppPurchase invalid product identifiers - Is it due to Pending Bank details?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, identifier

I have implemented In-App purchase in many apps. But in one of the recent app I'm getting InAppPurchase invalid product identifiers error. I believe is it due to Pending Tax, Bank, Contact status.

Here are my proper checklists:

- Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID? **YES**
- Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product? **YES**
- Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary? **YES**
- Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID? **YES**
- Are you using the full product ID when when making an
  SKProductRequest? **YES**
- Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes
  Connect? **YES**
- **Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect? NO**
- Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling? **YES**

I have already communicated the Pending bank status to client. So probably it will be done in couple of days.

Anyone can confirm that this is the only reason my in-app purchase implementation is not working ? If yes then how long I need to wait on successful submission of banking details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and my In-App started working as expected. 
Lemme answer my own question:

So the issue was definitely with the unavailability of bank details.

Steps to resolve:

1. Complete your bank detail first.
2. Now go back to your Manage In-App Purchases section.
3. If there is some yellow warning at the top then perform the below steps or jump to 7 directly.
4. Warning: Resolve your highlighted issues.
5. Go to the In-App Purchase Details section and edit your display name or description then click save.
6. You'll notice that your In-App status turned to Ready For Review
7. Test your app. It should be working fine now.